# Permission Errors When Creating a Directory

Tags: python

In this program I'm checking to see if a directory has been made, if it is then I will delete the directory and make a new one with the same name. If not then the program will carry on to the next step.

```
import shutil
import os

try:
    os.mkdir('Result')
except:
    shutil.rmtree('Result')
    os.mkdir('Result')
```

Here I am simply using shutil to remove the directory and then os to add the new one.

```
>>> os.mkdir('Result')
>>> FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Result'
```

However, I don't understand why I am receiving this problem, on some tries the program will work flawlessly with no errors, then on the next it will report back the same error.

The reason as to why I am deleting the folder is because it contains files that I no longer need, new files need to be added and if they are interfered with the program will become corrupt. These files will generally have the same name.

EDIT:
A Fix has been found as I needed to give permission when writing a new directory

```
os.mkdir('Result', 0o777)
```

Comment: From what I can see, there is nothing obviously wrong with your code. However, running just `os.mkdir('Result')` in the shell, as it appears you are doing, without the try-except block may result in the error since you don't have the exception handling logic in the case the directory already exists

Comment: That's my bad, it's not running in the shell - that's what it returns

Comment: Please show the whole traceback from the error.